# msbuild unit test - how to run separately?

Tags: msbuild

Currently, I have this msbuild script that scans Test DLLs and run once using msbuild /test

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="RunMSTest">

<ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="**\bin\*Test*.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="RunMSTest">
    <Exec Condition=" '@(TestAssemblies)' != ''"
          Command="Mstest.exe /nologo /resultsfile:TestResults.trx @

(TestAssemblies ->'/testcontainer:&quot;%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)&quot;', ' ')"
          />
</Target>

</Project>
```

Ideally, I want each Test DLL a separate mstest.exe and the file name saved to TestResults%(FileName).trx

Comment: have you tried to batch over TestAssemblies - e.g. instead of @(TestAssemblies) do %(TestAssemblies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separation of Microsoft Unit Tests to Reduce the Load of CI Server

https://helloacm.com/separation-of-microsoft-unit-tests-to-reduce-the-load-of-ci-server/